# Simple Do-Loop: Checking to see if the row data before is the same

Tags: loops, sas, do-loops

I'm used to coding in MatLab, SAS is still new to me when using Do Loops. My goal is to check the row above/before the current row to see if the current and previous row numbers match. If the vector data above the first row matches the current row, I want to be able to check this.

Num (column vector) = 123,123,134,156,290,348,596,569,569

```
/*---- Do-Loop ----*/
data full;
set work.Test;
 count=_N_;

do i=1 to count;
    Current = Num(i);
    Prev = Num(i-1);
end;

run;
```

To me "Current" should be referencing the i-th cell of the vector "Num" and "Prev" should be referencing the i-th cell before the "Current" cell. Can anybody help me?

Comment: The function for retrieving the value on a previous observation (row) is `lag()`. So you'd use `current=num; prev=lag(num);`. Referring to 'cells' in a SAS table makes things confusing, data is arranged in variables and observations (analogous to columns and rows respectively).

Comment: What about retrieving the next observation (row), what would that function be called?

Comment: That would be `lead()`

Comment: `lead()` does not exist in base SAS, and `lag()` does not precisely access the previous row's data.  It can be used as if it did that in some cases, but in this case it's probably better not to use it.  In particular, it does NOT work the way you expect it inside conditional statements, so if you do use `lag` for some reason, you should be careful to assign prev unconditionally.

Comment: Fair point @Joe, I must have confused it with the `lead()` that exists in non-SAS variants of SQL. I would also echo the reservations about `lag()`, I try to avoid it where possible.

Comment: I took it out of the do-loop completely and I am renaming it as a variable. Prev_Policy = lag(PolicyNbr) - after the policies are sorted. Are there any other options that are similar to lead() in base SAS?

Answer (score 1):

SAS is significantly different than Matlab in that Matlab has vectors and matrices, and base SAS does not.  Base SAS is closer to SQL than a matrix language; you manipulate columns inside of rows.  If you want to treat SAS like a matrix language, see if you have `SAS-IML` licensed (`PROC SETINIT; RUN;` should show you what you have licensed, or ask your SAS administrator).  That language is very very similar to Matlab.

As far as using base SAS to solve this, what you do depends on your goal.  If it's solely to compare every row to the previous row [or next row, since those two goals are identical], you can do this easily with `PROC COMPARE`.

For example:

```
data class_one/view=class_one;
set sashelp.class(firstobs=2);
run;

proc compare base=sashelp.class compare=class_one out=class_compare;
run;
```

There are lots of options with `PROC COMPARE` to get it to exactly what you want, see the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146741.htm) for more details.

You can also do a match merge to the next row very easily.

```
data want;
merge sashelp.class(in=a) sashelp.class(in=b firstobs=2 rename=(...) keep=...);
... do stuff ...
run;
```

You need to rename the variables coming in from the second dataset, though, since they'll overwrite the first dataset's variables otherwise, and use the `keep` option to only keep the ones you're working with - and `keep` uses the ORIGINAL name, not the renamed name.  Then in `...do stuff...` you put whatever code you are using to compare the row to the next row.  If 'previous row' is important (ie, you want rows [2..n] as final output, not [1..n-1]), then move the firstobs=2 to the first dataset.  (That tells it to skip the first observation, so one dataset starts at 1 and one starts at 2 and then both iterate beyond that.)

If you're just checking the row number, this is a little bit easier.  You can do this:

```
data want;
set have;
by num notsorted; *notsorted is needed unless you do expect it to be in numeric order;
if first.num then first_obs_for_rownum=1;
if last.num then last_obs_for_rownum=1;
run;
```

Obviously you can do other things with those `then` clauses, I'm just trying to be clear as to what they do.  `if first.num and last.num` would indicate that a row is unique by rownumber (at least, in the order on the dataset - if it is unsorted, that same num could appear elsewhere, but not immediately before/after that row).  `first.num` is a 1/0 variable that indicates whether the previous row had a different (1) or same (0) value for `num`; `last.num` is a 1/0 variable that indicates whether the next row has a different (1) or same (0) value for `num`.  Those can be used for any variable (so `first.id` `first.name` etc. work for those variables), so long as they appear on the `by` statement in some fashion; and if you have a multiple variable `by` statement, they are reset each time any variable to the left of that variable is reset.

Comment: I didn't notice at first that `num` was the only variable of interest, so the last part (Edited in) is probably the most useful answer, although it would be very easy to adapt the merge-forward as well.

Comment: You could also do a `proc sql` join of the dataset with itself on `a.num = b.num + 1`.

Comment: @Alex Not really.  First off, SQL doesn't respect row order, so the exact request to look at row order prevents you from using SQL unless you have a row number variable separate from the `num`.  Second, this particular suggestion runs counter to the request (if a.num=b.num, joined on the (imaginary?) row number variable).

Comment: I goofed on `num` there. I meant you could store `_n_` ahead of time and join on `a._n_ = b._n_ + 1` (not on `num`) and compare `num`.

Comment: Eh, you could, but it wouldn't be any faster or easier to code than a regular data step merge forward since you'd need a data step or at least a data step view in addition.

Comment: Truth. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching a code which checks the previous row's value and checks with the present value and update a column if there is a change.

Let me know if this helps.

```
Data Me;     
Input Pid Visit Dose;    
Cards;    
1 1 2    
1 2 3    
1 3 4    
1 4 4    
;
Run;

Data Me;
Set Me;
Length Dose_Change_Why $20.;
Dose_Change_Why = " ";
Run;

%Macro Chg;

Proc Sql;
Select Count(Dose) into:Cnt From Me;
Quit;

Data _null_;
Cnt = "&Cnt.";
Call Symput('Cnts', Compress(Trim(Cnt)));
Run;

Proc Sql;
Select Dose into:Dos1-:Dos&Cnts. From Me;
Quit;

%Do i = 1 %To &Cnt.-1;

Data _null_;
i = &i.;
j = &i. + 1;
Call symput('j', Compress(Trim(j)));
Run;

%If "&&Dos&i." ne "&&Dos&j." %Then %Do;
%Put &&Dos&i. &&Dos&j.;
Proc Sql;
Update Me set Dose_Change_Why = "Reason for change" Where Visit = &j.;
Quit;
%End;

%End;

%Mend;

%Chg;

Proc Print;
Run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Same can be achieved by lag function too.

```
Data Me; 
Input Pid Visit Dose;
Cards;
1 1 2
1 2 3
1 3 4
1 4 4
;
Run;

Data Me(Drop=Dose1); 
Set Me;
Dose1 = Lag(Dose);
If _n_ gt 1 and Dose ne Dose1 Then Why = "Reason";
Run;
```